# Drupal content access restriction

Tags: drupal

I'm using Drupal and IMCE to upload files to a private file system.  The problem is, I get an "Access forbidden" error whenever I try to access a file in it.  And this is using user 1, administrator.  Could anyone suggest how to properly set content access restrictions? I'm already using the "Content Access" module, but I guess I don't know how to use it properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it using the private/system url for the file instead of the direct sites/default/files/filename path

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/6